# Voice commanding a web browser on GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, open-source, voice-command, speech-recognition

I’d like to browse the Web by using voice commands.

It must be possible to scroll the page and to focus and click at links, and
it should be possible to fill in and submit forms.

- It must be **FLOSS** (Free/Libre Open Source Software).
- It must run on **GNU/Linux**.
- It must work with a **web browser** that is available for GNU/Linux.

  - Firefox preferred.

Comment: [This](http://www.simon-listens.org/index.php?id=128&L=1) seems to be one alternative for that. It is more generic than just browser commands. I haven't ever used it.